# Using Basemap 1.0.7 in Python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm creating a filled contour plot using m.contourf() form basemap(http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.contourf). For some reason ever since I upgraded to Python 3.6 and upgraded my packages numpy, scipy pandas etc, I keep getting this error. It worked fine in Python2.7 though.

Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/karthik/Documents/code/test_countourf.py", line 99, in <module>
    map.contourf(x, y, _arr, zorder = 0, cmap = _cmap, norm = cNorm, levels=levels)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 521, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3644, in contourf
    xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

My suspicion was that x.shape[0]/2 gives a float(since Python 3 I think) instead of an integer which might be the error since I didn't see the error in Python 2.7.

Any ideas on how to fix it in Python 3.6?

Thanks!

Comment: You could replace `x.shape[0]/2` by `x.shape[0]//2` as a quick fix, [just as it's already been done in the newest version](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py#L3529). In general, you may need to update matplotlib as well as basemap.

Comment: I used basemap 1.0.7. Looks like the Github repo is ahead of that release. Thanks!